# Unable to override toString() for ArrayAdapter in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, listview, google-app-engine, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to override toString method of my class Match, to use with ArrayAdapter. But the ArrayAdapter seems to have been ignoring the override and is still using the toString method of object class. Here is the code used in the Match class:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
  return getTeamA+" v "+getTeamB;
}
```

But the ArrayAdapter is returning a long twisted string which is a JSON representation of the object I guess, but certainly not what I want. Also please note that the Match class resides in the GAE backend module in the Android Studio. I have already done the following:

- rebuilt the project
- cleaned the project
- redeployed the backend to the GAE project

Every other operation is working fine, just not this one. Not throwing any errors either.

UPDATE:

Here is the code that uses it:

```
public static void printMatchList(Activity activity, ArrayList<Match> matches){
    ArrayAdapter<Match> matchArrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(activity,R.layout.textview,matches);
    ListView listView=(ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(matchArrayAdapter);
}
```

And the output in the device looks like this:

{"id":"1","teamA":"ABC","teamB":"XYZ","kind":"gameApi#resourcesItem"}

**And the output is same whether or not I use @Override for toString().**

ANOTHER UPDATE:

It turns out that the issue is with the GAE backend module. It appears that I cannot access any NEW methods which I add to the model class in the backend module. This is quite scary.
I have tried everything, rebuilding the app, restarting the Android Studio, re-deploying the backend module. Running out of options here.

Comment: What is the type of `getTeamA` and `getTeamB`

Comment: `But the ArrayAdapter is returning a long twisted string` what is that string like? and where is it returning that string?

Comment: @Clairvoyant both getTeamA and getTeamB are of the type String

Comment: Can you show the code where you have used `toString()`

Comment: override should work here because its a very basic code that you have written here. But the question Is what actually `getTemaA()` and `getTeamB()` Conains as a Object. ??? @goodsamaritan

Comment: @pskink I do not have the access to my system right now, but the string is something like: {"id":1,"teamA":"myTeam","teamB":"theirTeam",...}, so basically it has all the info about the Match object.